# Symfony 3. Cannot delete element with Doctrine. "a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails"

Tags: symfony, doctrine, cascade

I have 3 tables. "Dish". Connected with DishTypeAssoc (1..n). And DishTypeAssoc is connected with DishTypeOptionAssoc (1..n).

When I delete "Dish" from controller I got well working cascade deleting. When I delete Dish also DishTypeAssoc and DishTypeOptionAssoc is deleted.

```
        $em->remove($dish);
        $em->flush();
```

It is working fine.

But when I try to delete only DishTypeAssoc with corresponding DishTypeOptionAssoc using Doctrine,

I am using this function in DishTypeAssocRepository

```
        public function removeTypeAssoc($id = null)
        {
               $q = $this->createQueryBuilder('d')
               ->delete()
               ->where('d.dish = :id')
               ->setParameter('id', $id)
               ->getQuery()
               ->execute();

               return $q;
        }
```

I got an error:

An exception occurred while executing 'DELETE FROM r_dish_type_assoc WHERE dish_id = ?' with params [3]:

Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`preko_db7`.`r_dish_type_option_assoc`, CONSTRAINT `FK_4912176D382FD94` FOREIGN KEY (`dish_type_assoc_id`) REFERENCES `r_dish_type_assoc` (`id`))

---

This is my code of 3 Entities. Dish. DishTypeAssoc. And DishTypeOptionAssoc

```
class Dish
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="DishTypeAssoc", mappedBy="dish", cascade={"remove"})
     */   
    private $typeAssoc;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->typeAssoc = new ArrayCollection();
    }
//  ...setters - getters()
}


class DishTypeAssoc
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Dish", inversedBy="typeAssoc", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="dish_id",referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     */
    private $dish;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="DishTypeOptionAssoc", mappedBy="dishTypeOption", cascade={"remove"}) //, orphanRemoval=true)
     */   
    private $optionAssoc;

    public function __construct()
    {
       $this->optionAssoc = new ArrayCollection();
    }
//  ...setters - getters()
}


class DishTypeOptionAssoc
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="DishTypeAssoc", inversedBy="optionAssoc")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="dish_type_assoc_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true, onDelete = "SET NULL")
     */
    private $dishTypeOption;
//  ...setters - getters()
```

}

I dont know why Dish removing works well, and it deletes corresponding DishTypeAssoc and DishTypeOptionAssoc.

But removing only DishTypeAssoc and corresponding DishTypeOptionAssoc doesnt work.

Please, does anyone know why it returns an error ?

Answer (score 1):

Removing a Dish entity is working thanks to OrphanRemoval and removing cascade to completely delete the DishTypeAssoc and DishTypeOptionAssoc.

However, to delete a DishTypeAssoc, it has to be removed from the ArrayCollection **Dish->typeAssoc**

You need to remove it explicitly from the ArrayCollection.

To do this, you can use **onDelete="CASCADE"**

```
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Dish", inversedBy="typeAssoc", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="dish_id",referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true, onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    private $dish;
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly it doesnt work. I tried to add onDelete="CASCADE" to DishTypeAssoc Entity -> $dishTypeOption field too. :(   What does it mean "It has to be removed from the ArrayCollection Dish->typeAssoc" ?

Comment: You could try to remove the DishTypeAssoc in the array of typeAssoc in the Dish entity by using the doctrine method removeElement($element) on the ArrayCollection, there would be no constraint blocking you from deleting it this way